# How can I pass the variable between builds in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops

For example I have two builds A and B. When A build successfully, the build for B will be trigged and receives the output variable from A.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, there is no way to persist variables between two builds.

And there has an user voice [Make it possible to change the value of a variable in a variable group](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32350348-make-it-possible-to-change-the-value-of-a-variable) which suggest similar feature, you can vote and follow up.

And the workaround trigger build B after build A successful (variables can not be passed) is adding a related task (such as [Queue Build(s) Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jb.queue-build)) to queue build B at the end of build definition A.

Comment: What a pity!Thanks for explanation anyway.